# Is it possible to use C-written .so library file in an Angular 2+ project?

Tags: javascript, angular, shared-libraries

I'd like to create an Angular project but I need to use a custom C library which is historically used in my team.
I googled a lot about this but I did not find an answer to my doubt.
Is this a thing or do I need to re-implement the library in JS / switch to a different framework?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't run C in the browser, so you would have to rewrite the library in JS or take a look at [WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly)

Comment: You could potentially look at using webassembly. I don't have much experience with it, but it should work with Angular https://malcoded.com/posts/web-assembly-angular

Comment: You can keep your C-written code on the web server and make some HTTP requests into it with many different ways. Running the code inside web browser will be very tricky and better rewrite into JS. And finally if your Angular 2+ project is inside Electron or a similar system, then you can run C code, but this will be very similar to keeping it on web server

Comment: @Evgeniy that's a solution I would have considered if I could not find a way to "port" the native code automatically.

Comment: @dotconnor you're totally right, I hoped it was possible to "run" C code in a browser. The suggestion by you and user184994 to use WebAssembly seems to fit my needs; I did not know about this technology but it sound great!
Thanks for pointing me out to the right direction.